# My chart did show anything in android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I did some code but still im on the road to complete the whole chart.but at this moment I just want to show a CIRCLE in the emulator,just to make sure that im on the right path.but none of them is appear.the requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE ); is working but the rest is not.Help me.

```
package com.Sabry.yesbmi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;

public class Chart extends Activity {

    Paint paint;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );

        setContentView( R.layout.chart );

        initializeView();

    }

    private void initializeView() {

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor( Color.BLACK );
        paint.setStrokeWidth( 2 );
        paint.setTextSize( 20 );
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        setContentView( new Panel( this ) );

    }


    class Panel extends View {

         public Panel( Context context ) {
             super( context );
         }

    }

    public void onDraw( Canvas canvas ) {

         int originX = 10, originY = 800;
         canvas.drawColor( Color.WHITE );  // Background color
         canvas.drawCircle( 300, 80, 20, paint );

    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and format the code correctly.  It looks like you have the braces in all the wrong places.

Comment: Does the **onDraw()** is in **Panel** class??

Comment: yes it is..or is it im wrong?outside the panel class?

Answer (score 2):

I edited your question and formatted the code.  It is now very obvious that you have onDraw() outside the Panel class.  As you have it, it is a method of your Activity.

Here, I've removed the extra braces.

```
class Panel extends View {

    public Panel( Conext context ) {
        super( context );
    }

    public void onDraw( Canvas canvas ) {
        int originX = 10, originY = 800;
        canvas.drawColor( Color.WHITE );  // Background color
        canvas.drawCircle( 300, 80, 20, paint );    
    }

}
```

It is not required, but is good practice, to decorate overridden methods with the `@Override` annotation.  If you had done this, the compiler would have given you an error since `Acitivty` does not have an `onDraw` method.

Comment: Sory just now,so the problem is where?I dont understand.

Comment: ohh ok2...it is outside the panel class..hold on,try it first.

Comment: What I would do is make `Panel` a separate class, then add it to your chart.xml layout.